# iOS - ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, arm

When trying to run my iOS app on Iphone 5 or 4S simulator, I'm getting this error message:

> iOS - ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using Objective-C and iOS8 and Xcode 7.3.1 .
In Build Setting:

```
Architectures -> armv6,armv7,armv7s,arm64  
Build Active Architecture Only -> NO  
Valid Architectures  ->  arm64
```

Comment: Have you added AFNetworking by Pod or manually?

Comment: I didn't add this anywhere.no pod no manually.

Comment: Is the project running okay previously, when you start getting this error? Press Control+Command+K to hard clean.

Comment: No it's working on 5s,6 and  ... but does not working on 5 and 4s

Comment: Is the project started by yourself or you are working on a old project, also is it previously working on other devices, give detailed information so that people can help you easily.